# Edit Content of website without opening HTML file

Tags: html, css, web, edit

is there some other way to edit or change some text or pictures on my website using it's interface or not from the HTML file, cause my client is wondering on how can day update the "Events" Box(they don't know how to use HTML) i'm really new at this and open to any suggestions, thank you

Comment: You are looking for a Content Management System (CMS).

Comment: thank you for your answer sir

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are using. if you are using a CMS based program that would be possible.

you cannot edit a page without opening its files right of the browser without any external help.

Comment: so is this CMS thing an application?

Comment: its the backend of a site. you install it and create your site in it. then you can log in to the editing page and if you have done everything correctly you can edit the site's content there

Comment: thank you sir, ill take a look at it on youtube if there's some tutorial or something

Comment: I personally love the customization of Joomla + Gantry 5! But that's my opinion! xP

Comment: No problem. if its your first time using a CMS i recommend  Wordpress its slighly easier to use.

Comment: wordpress is not a free software isnt it?

Comment: it is a free software

Comment: but try to look at wordpress and bolt. they are both very usefull. u will have to learn some more things to use this.

Comment: on the tutorial that i just watched about wordpress as CMS, there's still a little "HTML" stuff that's used to edit it, don't know if my client would understand that, he's not a techy person

Comment: well. its the only easy option. and it does not have to be html. it can be plain text

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to edit the content of your website. Yes, its possible without opening any file using your CMS Dashboard. If the content is static then you have to open the `php/html` file.